# Add members dynamically to a class using Lua + SWIG

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, swig

This Lua code, creates a table and dynamically adds a new member. Running this I can get `"hello"` on the screen as expected:

```
foo = {}
foo.x = "hello"
print(foo.x)
```

But now I'm using SWIG to bind some C++ classes to Lua. 
For that purpose, in a `test.i` (SWIG module file) I created a simple class like this:

```
%module test

%inline
%{

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() { X = 0; }
  void SetX(int x) { X = x; }
  int GetX() { return X; }
private:
  int X;
};

%}
```

Then I wrote a test Lua code like that:

```
obj = test.Foo()
obj:SetX(5)
print("Number: " .. obj:GetX())
```

Running and getting `"Number 5"` as expected. The problem is that when I dynamically add a new member to my SWIG-binded object, and I try to access it, like so:

```
obj.Y = 7
print("Number: " .. obj.Y)
```

I get this error message:

```
"attempt to concatenate field 'Y' (a nil value)"
```

Is it possible to dynamically add new members on objects binded using SWIG? Is there some option without having to move to another Lua binding library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SWIG doesn't use tables for its objects; it uses *userdata*. After all, those objects are C++ objects, and need to store C++ data that Lua code shouldn't be able to touch.

And I wouldn't bother looking for "another Lua binding library"; pretty much *all* of them use userdata, which Lua code explicitly cannot modify (in order to provide the ability to do exactly this).

However, that doesn't mean you can't *cheat.*

You can always wrap the object you get from C++ code into your own Lua table, which would have a metatable that forwards unknown calls to the C++ object. The code to do so would look something like this:

```
local function WrapObject(cppObject)

    local proxy = {}

    local wrapper_metatable = {}

function wrapper_metatable.__index(self, key)
    local ret = rawget(self, key)
    if(not ret) then
        ret = cppObject[key]
        if(type(ret) == "function") then
            return function(self, ...)
                return ret(cppObject, ...)
            end
        else
            return ret
        end
    else
        return ret
    end

end


    setmetatable(proxy, wrapper_metatable)
    return proxy
end
```

The returned proxy object is a Lua table that can have keys and values set on it. When you get a value, such as to call a function, it will see if that value was set in the table. If not, it attempts to fetch it from the C++ object that you wrapped, which will go through *its* metatable.

You'll need to expand this metatable if your C++ class uses other metafunctions like `__add`, `__sub`, `__tostring` and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for answer so fast! Now I used the WrapObject function you posted. I've created a object: "obj = test.Foo()" and then wrapped: "wobj = WrapObject(obj)" but now, when I call "wobj:GetX()" I get this error message: "GetX (arg 1), expected 'Foo *' got 'table'". Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dani: Sorry, forgot about the self parameter. This could should work better.

Comment: It works! Awesome! :-) I don't know much about Lua metatables, and I've searched a lot for a solution like this. I believed it would be impossible... Thanks!